# djstripe customers not deleted

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have a test website that will be using stripe and [djstripe 0.8.0](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) for subscription payments.

I had the test data set up to test the payments system was working.

I then deleted the stripe test data.

However, when I open the django admin console and navigate to djstripe > customers, I have the following records displayed, but no users/customers attached to them:

[image]

There are no records in the corresponding database table. I have even deleted the customers from stripe and the database itself. Still cannot get rid of these records.

If I try to access the records or delete the records from the admin console, I receive the following error message:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'**

```
  File "C:\Users\me\desktop\myappname\env3\lib\site-packages\djstripe\settings.py", line 94, in get_subscriber_model_check_subscriber_for_email_address(subscriber_model, "The customer user model must have an email attribute.")
  File "C:\Users\me\desktop\myappname\env3\lib\site-packages\djstripe\settings.py", line 70, in _check_subscriber_for_email_address
    if ("email" not in subscriber_model._meta.get_all_field_names()) and not has attr(subscriber_model, 'email'):
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_field_names'
```

**How do I delete these records?**

Answer (score 0):

first I'd recommend updating to the latest djstripe version (I believe it's 1.0.0 as of now)

About deleting the records: 
Looking into the models.py *class Customer* from djstripe, it's clear that deleting the *default_source* (i.e. Stripe Customer) is not intended to delete the Customer from the djstripe tables

```
class Customer(StripeCustomer):
...
default_source = ForeignKey(StripeSource, null=True, related_name="customers", on_delete=SET_NULL)
```

as it is set to *on_delete=SET_NULL*

I would either reach out to the authors of djstripe ([authors](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authors.html)) (Daniel Greenfield is a great guy) or raise an issue on the corresponding GitHub page ([Github djstripe](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe))

In general I think, your software would initiate a deletion of a subscription. Deleting them in the Stripe interface leaves your code and djstripe for that matter out in the cold open :)

As a hardcore fix, I'd go directly into the corresponding database and delete those records.

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete user from your auth_user model; djstripe consider auth_user model as its customer model. Please read documentation for clarity.
https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable-1.0/reference/settings.html#djstripe-subscriber-model-settings-auth-user-model